# Java Printer: send documents to remote printers

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm dealing with a situation in which my swing application system has to send documents to a remote printer within a network that isn't the local one, but to which I have access (routers between networks allow this communication). Both networks do always have a private range of IPs. For instance: I'm trying to send a document from network 192.168.100.0 to a printer in 172.17.1.0 network (or the other way around).
Is this possible?

I've been googling and only found code samples regarding local printing. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

When using WIN7 OS u have option to add network / wireless printer to your pc. U have to add that network printer to your PC and simply open up printing dialog. User has to choose printer and its all done. ( Make sure with network administrator that u can see / add that printer [ router configuration firewalls etc... i dont know ] ).
This is how its done on WIN7 im sure it can be done on all other OSs.

Also about printing in java 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html

Comment: Thank you, seems a good option. I'll take a look to it and talk with network admin. However, does anybody else have any other idea? I was expecting to be able to "find" somehow remote printers from the Java code itself, without needing to register them in the OS as remote network printer.